# Show $p(X)$ (over a field) is irreducible iff $p(X+a)$ is irreducible

Tags: abstract-algebra, irreducible-polynomials

Let $A$ be a field and let $p(X)$ be a polynomial over $A$. Let $a\in A$.

Want to show:

> $p(X)$ is irreducible if and only if $p(X+a)$ is irreducible.

I suspect that I should use the substitution principle *somehow*, but that's as far as I've come. Completely stumped.

Comment: What can you say about the map $p(X) \mapsto p(X+a)$ from $A[X]$ to itself?

Comment: I would speculate that it's an automorphism, but how to prove that?

Comment: The "standard" proof that a map is an automorphism will work, there is really no special trick. (Just remember that $P(X+a)$ is not the same thing as $P(X)+a$.)

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1840572/279515

Answer (score 14):

One way to prove this is to instead prove that $p(X)$ is reducible if and only if $p(X + a)$ is reducible.

To this end, note that if $p(X) = q(X)r(X)$, then $p(X+a) = \hat{q}(X)\hat{r}(X)$ where $\hat{q}(X) = q(X + a)$ and $\hat{r}(X) = r(X + a)$. Going the other way, if $p(X+a) = q(X)r(X)$, then $p(X) = \tilde{q}(X)\tilde{r}(X)$ where $\tilde{q}(X) = q(X - a)$ and $\tilde{r}(X) = r(X - a)$.

Comment: But you need to also show that $\hat q (x)$ is not a unit, nor an associate of $p(x+a)$.

Comment: The units in $A[X]$ are the units in $A$. It follows that $q(X)$ is not a unit if and only if $\hat{q}(X)$ is not a unit.

Answer (score 6):

Hint: Show that $\phi_a:A[X]\to A[X]$ defined as $p(X)\mapsto p(X+a)$ is an automorphism.

Comment: Will this work over rings too?