# $p(x)$ is irreducible $\iff$ $p(x+c)$ is irreducible.

Tags: polynomials, ring-theory, irreducible-polynomials

Let $p(x)$ be a polynomial in $F[x]$, where $F$ is a field. Prove that $p(x)$ is irreducible $\iff$ $p(x+c)$ is irreducible for all $c \in F$.

This question has asked here before, like that:

[Show $p(X)$ (over a field) is irreducible iff $p(X+a)$ is irreducible](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/707537/show-px-over-a-field-is-irreducible-iff-pxa-is-irreducible)

However, I didn't understand the argument to prove that $p(x)$ irreducible implies $p(x+c)$ irreducible for all $c \in F$. Also, the otherside you just need to take $c=0$.

So, can you help me how to prove that?

Comment: Understanding and using the operations in the rings of polynomials, it{s not hard to see that the map $\;x\to x+c\;,\,\,c\in F$ , determines an automorphism of $\;F[x]\;$

Comment: I think you slightly misstate the fact from the other question; rather than "for all" it suffices for there to be just one $c$. I only mention this because for the purpose of calculations that is usually what you want. E.g. you show the $p$th cyclotomic polynomial $\phi$ is irreducible by checking that $\phi(x+1)$ is irreducible. It makes your converse "just take $c=0$" harder (but only slightly by using the symmetry of the statement like the answer below)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [Show $p(X)$ (over a field) is irreducible iff $p(X+a)$ is irreducible](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/707537/700480) they have proven that $p(x)$ reducible implies $p(x+c)$ reducible for all $c\in F$.

To prove the same about *irreducibility*, assume $p(x)$ irreducible. If $q(x)=p(x+c)$ was reducible for some $c\in F$, then $-c\in F$ and so $q(x+(-c))=p(x+(-c)+c)=p(x)$ would be reducible as per their proof - a contradiction.